# Keycloak Admin API: Unable to create a realm

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I want to create a realm in Keycloak using the [REST Admin APIs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/22.0.1/rest-api/index.html). Below is what I have done until now

- In the `master` realm, create a new client `custom-admin-api` .
- In the `Service accounts roles` of the client, assign the role of `realm-admin`.
- Generate the  `access_token` using the `client-id` and `client-secret`. The token has the below roles.

  ```
  {"resource_access":{"realm-management":{"roles":["view-identity-providers","view-realm","manage-identity-providers","impersonation","realm-admin","create-client","manage-users","query-realms","view-authorization","query-clients","query-users","manage-events","manage-realm","view-events","view-users","view-clients","manage-authorization","manage-clients","query-groups"]}}}
  ```
- Create the realm. I get an error response.

```
curl --location 'https://my-keycloak/auth/admin/realms' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer e...mFGA' \
--data '{
  "realm": "test",
  "displayName": "Test",
  "enabled": true
}'
```

```
403
{"error":"unknown_error"}
```

Can anyone guide me on what changes I need to make to create a new Realm?

**Note**: I'm able to create new users with the same `access_token`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way can do create realm by user's token

##### 1. In the master realm, create `custom-admin-api` client

And 'create-role` with create-realm.

```
Role name: create-realm
Description: ${role_create-realm}
```

[image]

[image]

##### 1. In the master realm, create a new power-user (password: 1234).

[image]

And `Assign Role` with `create-realm`

[image]

After Assign
[image]

##### Create Realm by Postman

Step 1. Tests Tab, setting

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("power-token", jsonData.access_token);
```

[image]

Step 2. Body Setting

[image]

Step 3 Get access-token
URL

```
POST http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

[image]

Step 5 Create Realm

Setting Token

[image]

Body

```
{"realm":"demo-realm","enabled":true}
```

[image]

[image]

##### Result

[image]

##### Create Realm by Curl

Get access token at Git Bash

```
POWER_TOKEN=$(curl --silent --location --request POST "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token" \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'username=power-user' \
--data-urlencode 'password=1234' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=admin-cli' | jq -r '.access_token')
```

Print access token

```
echo $POWER_TOKEN
```

[image]

Create realm

```
curl --silent --show-error -L -X POST "http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ""$POWER_TOKEN" \
--data '{"realm":"demo-realm-2","enabled":true}'
```

[image]

Result

[image]